# Como se puede descargar un fichero de imagen en .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Tengo la inquietud de cómo lograr descargar ficheros de imágenes mediante .NET, he leído que necesito trabajar con el método de variable Byte, pero no he encontrado una información exacta.
A continuación dejo mi código.

```
    public FileResult DescargarArchivo()
    {
        String ruta = "D:\\CarpètaArchivosPDF\\Yura.jpeg" ;
        byte[] result = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ruta);
        return File(result, ruta);
    }
```

Comment: Es un proyecto .NET Core o .Net Framework?

Comment: Hola, es Net Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En .NET Core MVC lo puede realizar de esta forma:

```
public FileResult Index()
        {
            
            string contentType = "image/png";//content type dependiendo del tipo
            //de archivo
            string extension = "png";//extensión del archivo
            string ruta =Path.Combine(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
                "logo_black."+extension);
            byte[] bites = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ruta);//lectura en bytes
            //si no se agrega este header la imagen solamente se muestra en la
            //página y si se agrega entonces se descarga
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition",
                $"attachment; filename=\"logo_black.{extension}\"");
            return File(bites,contentType);//resultado
        }
```

En mi caso la imagen se llama logo_black.png y la tengo en el escritorio, usted debe cambiar el nombre de la imagen,extensión y ruta según corresponda.

Comment: Si me funcionó, muchas gracias